# Need help porting jQuery to noConflict mode

Tags: magento, jquery

I've done some reading about jQuery noConflict mode, and am still struggling with it a bit.
I've got some code to function properly in noConflict mode, but have been unable to get the following to follow suit:

```
$.fn.infiniteCarousel = function () {

    function repeat(str, num) {
        return new Array( num + 1 ).join( str );
    }

    return this.each(function () {
        var $wrapper = $('> div', this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
            $slider = $wrapper.find('> ul'),
            $items = $slider.find('> li'),
            $single = $items.filter(':first'),

            singleWidth = $single.outerWidth(), 
            visible = Math.ceil($wrapper.innerWidth() / singleWidth), // note: doesn't include padding or border
            currentPage = 1,
            pages = Math.ceil($items.length / visible);            


        // 1. Pad so that 'visible' number will always be seen, otherwise create empty items
        if (($items.length % visible) != 0) {
            $slider.append(repeat('<li class="empty" />', visible - ($items.length % visible)));
            $items = $slider.find('> li');
        }

        // 2. Top and tail the list with 'visible' number of items, top has the last section, and tail has the first
        $items.filter(':first').before($items.slice(- visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items.filter(':last').after($items.slice(0, visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items = $slider.find('> li'); // reselect

        // 3. Set the left position to the first 'real' item
        $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);

        // 4. paging function
        function gotoPage(page) {
            var dir = page < currentPage ? -1 : 1,
                n = Math.abs(currentPage - page),
                left = singleWidth * dir * visible * n;

            $wrapper.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                scrollLeft : '+=' + left
            }, 500, function () {
                if (page == 0) {
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible * pages);
                    page = pages;
                } else if (page > pages) {
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);
                    // reset back to start position
                    page = 1;
                } 

                currentPage = page;
            });                

            return false;
        }

        $wrapper.after('<a class="arrow back">&lt;</a><a class="arrow forward">&gt;</a>');

        // 5. Bind to the forward and back buttons
        $('a.back', this).click(function () {
            return gotoPage(currentPage - 1);                
        });

        $('a.forward', this).click(function () {
            return gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
        });

        // create a public interface to move to a specific page
        $(this).bind('goto', function (event, page) {
            gotoPage(page);
        });
    });  
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.infiniteCarousel').infiniteCarousel();
})
```

Do I just replace all the '$' with 'jQuery'? Even in the return this.each(function() { ..., etc? All I have done is added the noConflict line to the end of my jQuery library in order to enable it. (I'm running Magento so it has conflicts with prototype, etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Tre

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An even easier solution might be to wrap everything in an immediately invoked anonymous function, and pass in the jQuery object to a $ argument like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
(function($) {
    //now I can use $ locally
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that but it will be messy.

You need to replace the `$` in front of selectors with `jQuery`. Because you have variables that start with `$`, you're going to have some pretty crazy variable names, like `jQuerywrapper` - I'd go through this code and change the selectors to jQuery and take the `$` out of the variable names altogether.

For example:

```
var wrapper = jQuery('> div', this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
```

Comment: @Regiel It is if there's going to be a mass find/replace of `$()` with `jQuery()`, assuming that is what he is using for noConflict(); ? If I'm mistaken please tell me :)

Comment: the OP asked, `Do I just replace all the '$' with 'jQuery'? `. You should say no... the variable names are just fine as what it is.. one solution would to just wrap everything up with `(function($){ all codes goes here })(jQuery)` ;) and now you are safe to use `$` variable inside..

Comment: I agree on all counts. @bstakes' solution is much more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function($){
 $.fn.infiniteCarousel = function () {

    function repeat(str, num) {
        return new Array( num + 1 ).join( str );
    }

    return this.each(function () {
        var $wrapper = $('> div', this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
            $slider = $wrapper.find('> ul'),
            $items = $slider.find('> li'),
            $single = $items.filter(':first'),

            singleWidth = $single.outerWidth(), 
            visible = Math.ceil($wrapper.innerWidth() / singleWidth), // note: doesn't include padding or border
            currentPage = 1,
            pages = Math.ceil($items.length / visible);            


        // 1. Pad so that 'visible' number will always be seen, otherwise create empty items
        if (($items.length % visible) != 0) {
            $slider.append(repeat('<li class="empty" />', visible - ($items.length % visible)));
            $items = $slider.find('> li');
        }

        // 2. Top and tail the list with 'visible' number of items, top has the last section, and tail has the first
        $items.filter(':first').before($items.slice(- visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items.filter(':last').after($items.slice(0, visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items = $slider.find('> li'); // reselect

        // 3. Set the left position to the first 'real' item
        $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);

        // 4. paging function
        function gotoPage(page) {
            var dir = page < currentPage ? -1 : 1,
                n = Math.abs(currentPage - page),
                left = singleWidth * dir * visible * n;

            $wrapper.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                scrollLeft : '+=' + left
            }, 500, function () {
                if (page == 0) {
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible * pages);
                    page = pages;
                } else if (page > pages) {
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);
                    // reset back to start position
                    page = 1;
                } 

                currentPage = page;
            });                

            return false;
        }

        $wrapper.after('<a class="arrow back">&lt;</a><a class="arrow forward">&gt;</a>');

        // 5. Bind to the forward and back buttons
        $('a.back', this).click(function () {
            return gotoPage(currentPage - 1);                
        });

        $('a.forward', this).click(function () {
            return gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
        });

        // create a public interface to move to a specific page
        $(this).bind('goto', function (event, page) {
            gotoPage(page);
        });
    });  
};
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.infiniteCarousel').infiniteCarousel();
})
```

**Explanation** :

```
(function($){
 // your code here
 $(document).ready(function(){

 });
})(jQuery);
```

is alternative to jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: So, if I set up code like that, then I don't need jQuery.noConflict(); ? If I did both, it'd cause problems, no?

Comment: If you did both, it would not cause problems because jQuery.noConflict gives up control of the global $, or more descriptively window.$. In the case of the anonymous function, when you pass in the global jQuery object (window.jQuery) and assign it to $, the local $ takes precedence over the global window.$. So, inside the anonymous function: window.jQuery === $, but window.$ !== $.