# Need help porting jQuery to Magento

Tags: jquery, magento

I ran into the same issue as the one in the post below. Can't figure out why this no conflict thing isn't budging. Any hints would be great.

my website http://www.tvlift.com/shop/accent-e.html

[Need help porting jQuery to noConflict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853948/need-help-porting-jquery-to-noconflict-mode)

```
(function () {
$.fn.infiniteCarousel = function () {
    function repeat(str, n) {
        return new Array( n + 1 ).join(str);
    }

    return this.each(function () {

        var $wrapper = $('> div', this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
            $slider = $wrapper.find('> ul').width(9999),
            $items = $slider.find('> li'),
            $single = $items.filter(':first')

            singleWidth = $single.outerWidth(),
            visible = Math.ceil($items.innerWidth() / singleWidth),
            currentPage = 1,
            pages = Math.ceil($items.length / visible);

        if ($items.length % visible != 0) {
            // pad
            $slider.append(repeat('<li class="empty" />', visible - ($items.length % visible)));
            $items = $slider.find('> li');
        }

        $items.filter(':first').before($items.slice(-visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items.filter(':last').after($items.slice(visible-1).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items = $slider.find('> li');

        $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);

        function gotoPage(page) {
            var dir = page < currentPage ? -1 : 1,
                n = Math.abs(currentPage - page),
                left = singleWidth * dir * visible * n;

            $wrapper.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({//'margin-left':'-=190px'
                scrollLeft : '+=' + left
            }, 500, function () {

                if (page > pages) {
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);
                    page = 1;
                } else if (page == 0) {
                    page = pages;
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible * pages);
                }

                currentPage = page;
            });
        }

        $wrapper.after('<a href="home-carousel-loop.html#" class="arrow back"></a><a href="home-carousel-loop.html#" class="arrow forward"></a>');

        $('a.back', this).click(function () {
            gotoPage(currentPage - 1);
            return false;
        });

        $('a.forward', this).click(function () {
            gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
            return false;
        });

        $(this).bind('goto', function (event, page) {
            gotoPage(page);
        });

        $(this).bind('next', function () {
            gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
        });
        });
        };
         })(jQuery);

          $(document).ready(function () {
           var scrolling = false;

           $('.homeCarousel').infiniteCarousel().mouseover(function () {
            scrolling = false;
            });

            setInterval(function () {
            if (scrolling) {
            $('.homeCarousel').trigger('next');
             }
             }, 2000);
              });
```

Answer (score 2):

The question you linked to has the correct answer.  Replace the first line,

```
(function () {
```

with this similar entry (notice the dollar sign),

```
jQuery.noConflict()
(function($) {
```

Towards the end of your script you still have some jQuery code outside of the closure, make sure this is the last line and not any sooner:

```
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid jquery conflict, the method normally I adopting is, add the following line very below of jquery file.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and then use this `j` instead of `$` sign. That will avoid jQuery conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to include  comma(,) after this sentence an
$single = $items.filter(':first')